# Xamarin Android: Select RecycleView row

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to select highlighting with a color a RecycleView row. I tried most of the online example for Xamarin Android but without success.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select high light with a color a RecycleView row.

`RecyclerView` does not handle item selection so you need do it yourself, add the following code in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` :

```
int selectedPosition = -1;
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
{
    (viewHolder as ViewHolder).TextView.SetText(dataSet [position],TextView.BufferType.Normal);

    if (selectedPosition == position)
        viewHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Pink);
    else
        viewHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);

    viewHolder.ItemView.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        selectedPosition = position;
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    };
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNRB0.gif).