# Xamarin Android:How to change the color of selected rows in a recyclerview

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello everyone my name is Taniguchi and i am using recyclerview and i have two questions:
1. How to select multiples rows in recyclerview when i click then
2. How change the color of this selected rows.
Every documentation i found about this is for android using java.

my click listener:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView mName;
        public TextView mSubject;
        public TextView mMessage;

        // Get references to the views defined in the CardView layout.
        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener, Action<object, View.LongClickEventArgs, int> longClickListener)
            : base(itemView)
        {
            // Locate and cache view references:
            mName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            mSubject = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            mMessage = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);


            // Detect user clicks on the item view and report which item
            // was clicked (by position) to the listener:
            itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.Position);
            ItemView.LongClick += (sender, e) => longClickListener(sender, e, base.Position);
        }

    }
```

My recyclerview adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        // add this variable
        private Boolean isSelected = false;

        public Boolean IsSelected()
        {
            return isSelected;
        }

        public void setSelected(Boolean selected)
        {
            isSelected = selected;
        }
        private Activity mActivity;
        private MyActionMode mActionMode;
        private List<Email> mEmails;
        private Context context;
        private ActionMode mode;
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
        public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Context context)
        {
            mEmails = emails;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Activity activity)
        {
            mEmails = emails;
            mActivity = activity;
        }
        public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public View mMainView { get; set; }
            public TextView mName { get; set; }
            public TextView mSubject { get; set; }
            public TextView mMessage { get; set; }

            public MyView(View view) : base(view)
            {
                mMainView = view;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How to select multiples rows in recyclerview when i click then

Have a look at this [Multiselect recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610629/multiselect-recyclerview)

> 2. How change the color of this selected rows.

Here is a similar discussion. [Xamarin Android: Select RecycleView row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607726/xamarin-android-select-recycleview-row)